# how do you delete the line with the biggest number from a text file python?

Tags: python, del

```
with open('winnernum.txt', 'r') as b:
  data = b.readlines()
  gone=(max(data))
  print(gone)
with open("winnernum.txt","r") as h:
  del gone
```

I've tried this and other variations of this code in python but it still won't delete. I need to print the top 5 largest numbers from a text file.

I've attempted using this before:

```
with open('winners.txt', 'r') as b:
  data = b.readlines()
  gone=(max(data))
  print(gone)
import heapq
print(heapq.nlargest(5, winner))
```

but that doesn't always pick the top 5 numbers and tends to select them at random. Please help!

Comment: `readlines` gives you a list of strings. you want to convert them to a list of ints/floats

Comment: Does each line contain only a single number?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to, at the very least, open the file for writing?

Comment: Each line has one number in it yes.

Comment: How would i go about turning it into floats/ints instead of readlines?

Comment: `list_of_floats = [float(str.strip(line)) for line in b]`

Comment: thanks, where in my code do you want me to put that and do you think that is the only issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
from heapq import nlargest

with open("winnernum.txt", "r") as f:
    numbers = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f.readlines()]
    largest = nlargest(5, numbers)

print(largest)
```

Comment: i have tested this and nothing has been displayed. is there a part of this that i need to print or return

Comment: @katy `largest` is the list containing the 5 largest numbers of your file. You can do whatever you want with that list. For example, you can print it with `print(largest)` (see my edit)

Comment: thank you! this works really well however i also need to attach a username to each high score. sorry, i didn't include this in my original question but it wouldn't allow this program to work because you can't convert a string to a float. do you see a way around this? If not, thank you anyway this has been very helpful.

Comment: @katy please open a new question!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(open('winners.txt', 'r')) as file:
    gone = max(map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n'), file.readlines()))

print(gone)
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work but how would I repeat this a total of 5 times in order to get the top 5 scores without repeating the same score again and again?

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It is only finding the maximum number, not the 5 largest numbers

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault to not read question correctly. Thank you for your advice.